# C# WPF Binding between WebBrowser and TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, binding, textbox

im working on a password secured browser but the Binding i made between the Textbox (for iput uri) and the WebBrowser dont work as hoped. Im already several hours in the making of the Binding and this is the first time even something works.

What my Binding should do: Just to "synchronize" browser uri and Textbox.

What it actually do: When i write a link in the textbox (for example google.de) the browser navigates to google and the Textbox updates to the actual full uri. when i search something in google or go to google pics, the textbox dont update.

XAML:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="address"
                         Height="30"
                         Margin="5" 
                         MinWidth="400"
                         KeyDown="Go_Uri_KeyDown"
                         Text="{Binding ElementName=browser, Path=Source.AbsoluteUri, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         FontSize="18"
                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         />
<WebBrowser x:Name="browser" 
                        Margin="5,45,5,5" 
                        Source="https://google.de"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    />
```

The Eventhandler of the textbox to navigate:

```
private void Go_Uri_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(this.address.Text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                {
                    string url = "https://" + this.address.Text;
                    this.address.Text = url;
                    uri = new Uri(this.address.Text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                this.browser.Navigate(uri);
            }
        }
```

if you need any further Information to help, i will provide everything i can.

Comment: If you spin it up in visual studio and use live visual tree or snoop to take a look at the property.  What is source of the webbrowser control once you've navigated in the webbrowser control?

Comment: i cant spin it, because the Source property of the WebBrowser is not a dependency Property. And when i navigate in the Browser the source is the page im on at that moment. Or did i fully misunderstood you?

Comment: By spin it up I mean press f5 and run it.  But If you bind using elementname then whatever you have in your path must be a dependency property or your binding will not work. Which could well be your problem.

Comment: I tested a bit and the problem is that the Browser source isnt a dependency property. But how can i manage to Bind the Textbox and the Browser source even the Browser source isnt a dependency property? I mean in the known Browsers like for example Firefox its working to keep the browser source and the url-textbox synchron.